# Is It Possible to Set My Swift App As the Default App For SMS

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, app-store

On Android, there is a way to create an app and set it your default SMS app for example. That app now becomes the default app for handling SMS. I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this on iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple currently doesn't let you set any third party app as a default for SMS.
You can only do so for email and web browser.